# Create request rate limiting for all API instances under APIM

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is it possible to create a policy that limites request rate over a period for all API instances?

Can the policy below be used for the requirement?

Please note I want the policy to be define in one place (global, that is, "All APIs"), not repeated for every API instance.

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <rate-limit calls="20" renewal-period="90" />
    </inbound>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
</policies>
```

> Policy sections: inbound
>
> Policy scopes: product

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#LimitCallRate

Answer (score 1):

yes. You can add this policy inside "ALL APIS" policy section. It will get effect for all the APIs. Its's correct

Comment: Do you have document, or tested it? The document only mentions "Product".

Comment: rate-limit is supported in product, API, and operation scope. rate-limit-by-key - at all scopes. We'll update the docs.